# search input angular Ng2SearchPipeModule,

Tags: angular, typescript, api, input

I did an input search with **ng2SearchPipeModule** but it doesn't work I can't find my error?,
in my html all my books are in divs will when i type a book title all the div will be displayed?,

of course I imported in app.module.ts
**Ng2SearchPipeModule**,
**FormsModule**

i have 2 errors

1 - Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'BookType'.

2 - nothing is happening in my html

**service.ts**

```
export class BookService {

  url: string = 'http://henri-potier.xebia.fr/books';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBookList(): Observable<BookType> {
    return this.http.get<BookType>(this.url);
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookType } from '../models/book-type';
import { BookService } from '../services/book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  public bookType: BookType;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bookService.getBookList().subscribe(data => {
      this.bookType = data
    });
  }

  search() {
    if(this.bookType.title == "") {
      this.ngOnInit();
    }else{
      this.bookType = this.bookType.filter(res =>{
        return res.bookType.title.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.bookType.title.toLocaleLowerCase());
      })
    }
  }

}
```

**html**

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="bookType" (ngModelChange)="search()"
    placeholder="Rechercher">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let book of bookType" class="form-group">
            <div class="product-img">
                <img [src]="book.cover" alt="livre" height="420" width="327">
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
                <div class="product-text">
                    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{book.synopsis}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price-btn">
                    <p>{{book.price | currency: 'EUR'}}</p>
                    <button type="button" (click)="addBookToCart()">buy now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**interface**

```
export interface BookType {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    cover: string;
    synopsis: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you get the `bookType` as an array because you iterate it with `*ngFor` try to declare `bookType` like this:

```
public bookType: BookType[];
```

This shows that the property is filled with `BookType` in an array.
When you will do this you will be able to use `this.bookType.filter()` because `filter()` iterates through an array.

Hope this solves it.

**Edit: In response to your message in the comments**

Create another property of type `BookType` like this:

```
public searchedBook: BookType;
```

Notice this time it's without the array type `[]`
Now use it in the `ngModel` like this:

```
[(ngModel)]="searchedBook"
```

Then do this:

```
this.bookType = this.bookType.filter(res =>{
        return res.title.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchedBook.title.toLocaleLowerCase());
})
```

Comment: I modify it like this: search() {
    if(this.bookType == "") {
      this.ngOnInit();
    }else{
      this.bookType = this.bookType.filter(res =>{
        return res.title.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.bookType.title.toLocaleLowerCase());
      })
    }
  }               but I have an error: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'BookType[]' and 'string' have no overlap.   at the level of the if condition

Comment: thank you for your help and time spent, I still have an error:                                   
Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined